# Neural net: no dropout gives the best test score. Is that bad?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dropout, regularized

I took over some code from someone and my task was to reproduce the same model and performance in pytorch. I was given best hyper-parameters for that model as well. After playing around with it for quite sometime, I see that if I set drop out rate to zero, then my test performance is the best. it stops earlier, the smaller dropout is. In fact it outperforms previous model a bit. While the previous model had significant dropout rates.
The data size is about 33 million rows. And the neural net is like 4-5 layers. Total input embedding is ~1000.
Though I am happy to see the performance, I am wondering if it is some kind of red flag. Because without dropout i don't really have any other regularization. And it performing good with this may mean there might be some data leakage or something?
Looking for some wisdom around dropout in this context.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because i is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML methodology.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, these things happen. Once my neural-net was not working and so I was advised to add Batch Normalization layers in it, and then it worked so well. But then in another problem, Batch Normalization made my neural-net worse. This is all because of backpropagation. Sometimes, adding some layer makes the neural-net get stuck in a local-minimum, while sometimes it helps to get out of it. I am not quite sure why is this, but I think it is because of BackPropagation.

> might be some data leakage or something?

The answer is no. Its just because of backpropagation.

NOTE - If you feel I am wrong anywhere in this post, then please comment it.